# Smooth Operators in Groovy

Tags: groovy, apache-commons

What am I missing here? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg10255/index.html

In reference to Listing 1: Why is

```
lamp1 <=> lamp2
```

equal to a positive number but

```
"black"<=>"blue"
```

is a negative number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad example.  In the `LavaLamp.compareTo` method the comparison is being built with `this` on the right-hand side and the other object on left-hand side.  The usual convention is the reverse.

So when you do `lamp1 <=> lamp2`, you're effectively doing `lamp2.baseColor <=> lamp1.baseColor`.

Comment: Good catch.  I felt this wasn't a challenging question but I guess I looked at it too long.  I wonder why the author defines the equals method in the conventional way but does not with compareTo.  Thanks.